# Use of system > configuration > design and System > Design

Tags: theme, design

Hi can any one explain

Differences and similarities between `System > Configuration > Design` and `System > Design` to configure the design fallback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system > configuration > design is used to set the default theme for the store whereas the system > design is used to set seasonal design themes with time interval. i.e. the design lasts from a specific start date to a specific end date.

Comment: It should also be noted that the configurations in `System > Design` are entirely optional; it does not need to be configured. The more important configuration is always the `System > Configuration > Design` section, where the default theme is set for all stores and store views.

Answer (score 2):

See `System > Configuration > Design` is generally use for setting permanent Design of your site.

and `System > Design` is used for if you want to changed design for any festival then you can use this one  and select the start date and end date. so on that time period this new design will be show.